# How to pass state/data with useNavigate hook in react-location?

Tags: reactjs, react-routing, react-location

I have been trying to pass a state to the other page via route while using the `useNavigate` hook in the `react-location`. I looked all over the internet for it and couldn't find a solution. All the answers I found were for `react-router`, but I need it with the `react-location`. Does anybody have any idea about it?

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-location';

// And inside the component
const navigate = useNavigate();

// To navigate
navigate({to: path})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need to share state/data using the `search` key. This is how I did it.

```
navigate({to: path, search: state})
```

Just dropping my answer here so it could help others if they face the same issue. Thanks